# How to recreate UIViewController stack?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload, loadview

I'm writing a 'load' feature for my current iPhone app.

Practically what I want to do is get the user back where s/he left off. To do so I want to recreate all the `UIViewController`s appeared before.

My problem is the `UIViewController`s won't appear if I simply call `[[self navigationController] pushViewController:newController animated:YES];`.

The same code works fine when invoked as an event handler, like after touching a button. But if I do same without an even (for ex. in `viewDidLoad`) the new view controller's `loadView` method won't get called.

My actual code (with some pseudo elements):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (loading)
        [self onSomeEvent];
}

- (void)onSomeEvent {
    UIViewController *newController = //init....;
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
    [newController release];
}
```

I guess `viewDidLoad` is not the right place to do such a call, but then what is?

Comment: Are you trying to restore the state of the app when user runs it again?  See if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360578/iphone-navigationcontroller-autoloading-to-three-level/2360901#2360901

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that spreading your "load" feature all accross your controllers is the best way to achieve it.

I would rather put it in the init of your application, in the `applicationDidFinishLauching` part. Then you have a centralized place where you restore the previous state (easier to handle IMHO).

Let's suppose you want to implement some more advanced restore feature like:

- displaying a splash UIView with an activity indicator to indicate the user that you're restoring previous state
- restore the stack of your controllers in the navigation controller
- remove the splash

it's easier to have all this code in the applicationDidFinishLauching : it's all managed at one point.

Morever, when restoring the old state to your navigation controller, you can avoid using the transitions and use `animated:NO` instead of `YES` when pushing your controllers. It will be easier to handle from your perspective and the restore time may be decreased if you remove time needed to achieve transitions.